# ksh + compare numbers – two ways

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ksh

the following example shows hot to compare numbers 
I give here two different ways

one way with the ">" and "<" 
and second way with "-gt" or "-lt"

both ways are work exactly
so what the differences between them ? or maybe there are not difference ?

example 1

```
  ksh



  a=1
  b=2
  [[ $a > $b ]] && echo ok
  [[ $a < $b ]] && echo ok
  ok
```

example 2

```
  ksh

  a=1
  b=2
  [[ $a -gt $b ]] && echo ok
  [[ $a -lt $b ]] && echo ok
  ok
```

Answer (score 3):

In your examples there are no difference, but that is just an unfortunate choice of values for a and b.

-lt, -gt are for numeric comparison

< and > are for alphabetic comparison

```
 $ a=12
 $ b=6
 $ [[ $a -lt $b ]] && echo ok
 $ [[ $a < $b ]] && echo ok
ok
```